# How can I test my external API calls without having to push my code changes to my Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, webserver

### Question Rephrase:

Can I configure my local web server to be connected to the public internet so that I can test my API calls locally?

### Details: (edited)

**I'm still looking for some help on this.  It seems that there is a compatibility issue from what I can gather from many Google searches.  Has anyone out there used the gem Proxylocal on a Windows machine?  Did you need to perform any extra steps to get it to work because you were on a Windows machine?**

I am using Ruby on Rails and Heroku for deployment.

I was pointed to Pow ([pow.cx](http://pow.cx/)), but this only works on macs.  I am running Windows 8.  Does anyone have a suggestion for me?  Thanks!

### Update:

I was unable to install the proxylocal gem.  I receive the following error upon entering `gem install proxylocal` in my command line prompt:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing proxylocal:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating decode-i386-mingw32.def
compiling decode.c
decode.c:3:24: fatal error: netinet/in.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [decode.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bert-1.1.6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bert-1.1.6/ext/bert/c/gem_make.out
```

And this is the contents of gem_make.out:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
generating decode-i386-mingw32.def
compiling decode.c
decode.c:3:24: fatal error: netinet/in.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [decode.o] Error 1
```

Does anyone have an idea of what might be the issue here?  I don't see any spaces in the paths I have my gems installed in, which seems to be a common cause to this error for a lot of people...

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [proxylocal gem](https://github.com/proxylocal/proxylocal-gem)

Comment: OMG.  I do believe this is exactly what I was looking for.  I will install it and try it out.  If it works, I will accept this answer.  Thank you so much.

Comment: How would I install this gem only on my local environment?

Comment: Just remember to start the rails server first and then the proxylocal. From terminal run `gem install proxylocal` to install then `proxylocal 3000 --host testhost` to use

Comment: but won't this install the gem in production as well?

Comment: It does not go in the gemfile. You install via terminal on the local machine only. After installation you run `rails s` and then `proxylocal 3000 --host testhost` (or whatever name you want to give the host) and then access your app via `http://testhost.t.proxylocal.com/`. When you stop the rails server or proxylocal it wont be accessible anymore.

Comment: I have updated my question, would you be able to take a look at what I got as a result of running `gem install proxylocal` in the command line?

Comment: do you have any other ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, but I found that, it's not proxylocal's problem, it's bert's problem, see the error log:

```
Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bert-1.1.6 for inspection.
```

It's because with bert distribution, linux headers are being provided, I have [posted here a solution](https://github.com/proxylocal/proxylocal-gem/issues/11) for the same after testing it on my windows system. Please have a look and let me know, it you were able to solve it or not!